# Как убрать elevation у дочерней активности?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragment

Существует activity_main, fragment_main и ещё одна активность, которая запускается по нажатию айтема из списка который находится в fragment_main. Так вот эта активность запускается со стандартным тулбаром. И собственно сабж, как у этого тулбара убрать тень?
З.Ы на activity_main я убрал таким способом (app:elevation="0dp") :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Данной строкой в коде активности, в которой я хочу убрать тень, я добился нужного результата: `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`

Answer (score 0):

в `styles.xml` в главный стиль добавьте этот итем

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.Никаких изменений не произошло.

Comment: а полностью стиль покажите

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rq0Y1LCA